# Bind values from datagridview to radiobutton

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I need to bind datagridview values from **form2** to radiobutton in **form1** when double click. I just get this error **Conversion from string "Male" to type 'Boolean' is not valid**. How can I fix this

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub dgCostumerSearch_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgCostumerSearch.CellDoubleClick

    Try
        costumer.txtcostID.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
             .Cells(0).Value

        costumer.txtcostName.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
             .Cells(1).Value

        costumer.txtcostLastName.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
             .Cells(2).Value

        If dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.Equals("Male") Then
            costumer.rbMaleCost.Checked = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
                 .Cells(3).Value
        End If
        If dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.Equals("Female") Then
            costumer.rbFemCost.Checked = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
                .Cells(3).Value
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says everything. You trying set value of type `String` to property of type `Boolean` in the line:

```
costumer.rbMaleCost.Checked = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index) _
             .Cells(3).Value
```

And next is code which might work

```vb
Private Sub dgCostumerSearch_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgCostumerSearch.CellDoubleClick

    Try
        costumer.txtcostID.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value

        costumer.txtcostName.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value

        costumer.txtcostLastName.Text = dgCostumerSearch.Rows(dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2).Value

        If dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.Equals("Male") Then
            costumer.rbMaleCost.Checked = True
        End If
        If dgCostumerSearch.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.Equals("Female") Then
            costumer.rbFemCost.Checked = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```